# Synopsis Codesight doesn't work in subfolder

Tags: visual-studio-code, coverity

Okay, I have the following project structure

```
- MegaDirectory
--- SubProject1
----- coverity.conf
--- SubProject2
```

These subprojects are handled as git submodules.
I use codesight plugin with visual studio code.

I have created the following `coverity.conf` file in the first subproject.

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://URL.com/schemas/coverity.conf.schema.json",
     "type": "Coverity configuration",
     "format_version": 1,
     "format_minor_version": 7,
     "settings": {
          "cov_run_desktop": {
               "build_cmd": ["make","-C", "$(code_base_dir)/build"],
               "clean_cmd": ["make","-C", "$(code_base_dir)/build","clean"]
          },
          "ide": {
               "build_strategy": "CUSTOM"
           }
     }
}
```

If I open the subproject folder as the root folder inside vs-code and edit a file from it, I get the codesight output and everything works ok.

If I open the `MegaDirectory` as the root folder inside vs-code and edit a file from the subproject, I get an error that this file is uncaptured.

I have been delving into the configuration of codesight, but I got nothing useful.

Is there a solution to this ?

Thanks

Comment: Is your path limit crossing 260 characters ? Please try using SYNOPSYS_HOME= /path variable .

Comment: https://community.synopsys.com/s/article/Code-Sight-Uncaptured-File-Error-due-to-project-path-length